# JQuery .Find() not working in IE11 and Chrome when searching elements from MVC editor template

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC view (partial shown below):

```
<div class="section roundedbox" id="results">
    <div class="section-title roundedbox center ui-widget-header">@Html.LabelFor(p => p.SOWProductCodes)</div>
    <div class="section-content ui-widget-content">
        @if (Model.SOWProductCodes.Count > 0)
        { <table class="list">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 5%" class="center">
                        Remove
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 50%">@Html.LabelFor(p => p.SOWProductCodes[0].ProductCodename)
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 30%">@Html.LabelFor(p => p.SOWProductCodes[0].BoxMaterial)
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 5%">
                        Save
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @Html.EditorFor(p => p.SOWProductCodes, new
               {
                   SOWId = Model.SOWId
               })
            </tbody>
        </table> }
        else
        {
            <div class="center">
                No related products codes found.<br />
                At least one product code must exist to continue.</div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

It references the following editor template:

```
@model Product.Web.Models.ProductCode
<tr>
<td style="width: 5%" class="center">
    @using(Html.BeginForm("RemoveProductCode", "Details", FormMethod.Post))
    { 
        <input type="hidden" value="@Model.ProductCodeId" name="ProductCodeId"/> 
        <input class="center" id="remove" type="image" value="Remove" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Cancel.png")" width="24px" height="24px" alt="Remove" />
    }
</td>
@using(Html.BeginForm("UpdateProductCode", "Details", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    <td style="width: 50%">
        <input type="text" value="@Model.ProductCodename" name="ProductCodename"/>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 45%">

        <input type="text" value="@Model.BoxMaterial" name="BoxedMaterial"/>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 5%" class="center">
        <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.SOWId" name="SOWId"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="@Model.ProductCodeId" name="ProductCodeId"/>
        <input class="right" id="save" type="image" value="Update" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Ball Green Check.png")" width="24px" height="24px" alt="Update" />
    </td>
} 
</tr>
```

The following JQuery works on all views (via IE11) that are not using an editor template. For the above view it works in IE11 but only when using F12 in IE 9 mode:

```
/toggles chages on input change
$('input, textarea, select').live('change', function (element) { ToggleChange(true, element); });});

function ToggleChange(changed, element) {
var form = element.currentTarget.form;

if (changed) {
    $('#changed').html('*');
    //Enable save
$(form).find('input[id="save"]').removeAttr('disabled');
$(form).find('input[id="save"]').show(); 
    $(form).find('img[id="warning"]').hide();
}
else {
    $('#changed').html('');
    //disable save
    $(form).find('input[id="save"]').hide();
    $(form).find('input[id="save"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
};
}
```

I am able to make the input show by using $('input[id="save"]').show(). However, the above JQuery is used globally and thus I pass in the form which contains the "save" input I want to show/hide.

This was working until customers started upgrading to IE10 and above. I recall it also working in earlier versions of Chrome.

Comment: What version of jQuery? `.live()` was depreciated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

Comment: I am using version 1.7.1 and just to be sure I updated to using .on() in place of .live(). Still seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this section:

```
</td>
@using(Html.BeginForm("UpdateProductCode", "Details", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    <td style="width: 50%">
```

Your form code is showing up between the TD tags.

Comment: You are correct. I put the form inside a new cell and then add the form around a new table inside that cell and it works now.